# Как создать двунаправленный канал между процессами?

Tags: php, c++, posix

В моем проекте мне потребовалось запустить php скрипт из с++, передать ему stdin, и забрать stdout.Чтоб это сделать я создаю дочерний процесс с помощью fork(), открываю каналы с помощью pipe(), переназначаю птоки ввода/вывода через dup2 и запускаю скрипт с помощью execlp(). 
Я написал небольшую программу для тестов, но она не работает, зависает на read, он ждет пока дочерний процесс что то запишет в pipe, но этого не происходит, что я делаю не так?

Кода на с++:

```
int main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   int pipe_in[2];
   int pipe_out[2];
   pipe(pipe_in);
   pipe(pipe_out);
   if ((pid = fork()) > 0) // родительский процесс
   {
    close(pipe_in[0]);  // закрываем возможность чтения
    close(pipe_out[1]); // закрываем возможность записи

    std::string msg = "hello world";
    char buf[256];
    write(pipe_in[1], msg.c_str(), msg.length());
    read(pipe_out[0], buf, 255);
    std::string temp = buf;
    std::cout << temp;
   }
   else
   {
       close(pipe_in[1]); // закрываем возможность записи
       close(pipe_out[0]); // закрываем возможность чтения
       dup2(pipe_in[0], 0);
       dup2(pipe_out[1], 1);
       if(execlp("php", "/home/anton/test1.php",  NULL) < 0)
           std::cout <<"(((";

   }
```

}

используемый php скрипт:

```
<?php
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo $line;
echo "11111";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы запускаете `execlp` неправильно:

```
if(execlp("php", "/home/anton/test1.php",  NULL) < 0)
    std::cout <<"(((";
```

В руководстве [сказано](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp):

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed. The array of pointers must be
>   terminated by a NULL pointer.

Это означает, что в качестве второго аргумента для `execlp` нужно передать строку, содержащую имя исполняемого файла. Это то, что будет доступно как `argv[0]` в дочернем процессе.

То есть первый аргумент `php` - это имя исполняемого файла интерпретатора PHP, второй аргумент `php` - это "нулевой" аргумент для исполняемого файла (`argv[0]`). И уже далее мы указываем какой PHP файл интерпретатор должен выполнить.

Говоря проще, добавьте ещё одну строку `php` в вызов `execlp`:

```
   if(execlp("php", "php", "/home/anton/test1.php",  NULL) < 0)
       std::cout <<"(((";
```

---

Далее.

Чтобы ваш пример заработал, передаваемая строка должна заканчиваться на `\n`, так как функция PHP [`fgets`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), будучи вызванной без второго аргумента, не возвратит результат, до тех пор, пока не обнаружит новую строку.

---

Кстати, бросается в глаза отсутствие обнаружения ошибок в этом коде. Даже если это просто программа для теста, то для тестирования совсем не помешало бы знать о случающихся ошибках, чтобы иметь представление о том, почему что-то идёт не так.