Код для стресс тестирования на Python
хочу написать стресс тестирование кода на c++, однако генератор у меня на питоне. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ(метод или библиотека), чтобы автоматически вводить входные данные из .py в .exe, и получать вывод в тот-же .py файл?(Желательно с пояснением)

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1060469/178988
